# What is the geometric meaning of $\frac{c\cdot n}{p\cdot n}-1$, for $c$ a point on a plane, $n$ a unit normal, and $p$ some other point?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I'm trying to understand some piece of code and have the following expression:

> `Dot(c,n)/Dot(p,n) - 1.0`
>
> representing $$\frac{c\cdot n}{p\cdot n}-1$$

where $c$ is a point on the plane, $n$ is the (normalized) plane normal, $p$ is some other point that is not on the plane. `Dot` is a function that returns the dot product between the two arguments passed to it.

I think it's got something to do with the distance of $p$ to the plane, but I can't quite figure out what the exact geometrical meaning of this expression is.

Can someone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "Dot"? Does, e.g., "Dot(c, n)" refer to the dot product between $c$ and $n$?

Comment: exactly, dot means dotproduct between c and n

Comment: $c\cdot n$ is the (signed) distance between the plane and the origin. $p\cdot n$ is the same, except for a plane passing through $p$ parallel to the original plane.

Comment: @Rahul thank you, that already gives me a way to think about it

Comment: maybe as additional context, this is part of the cost function in a optimizer. `residual = (center_dot_normal / point_dot_normal - 1.0)` it seems this term is zero if p lies exactly on the plane

Comment: Is it correct to say that this is the distance of p to the plane relative to the distance of the plane to the origin?